# fp-ts: Option<T>[] to Option<T[]> with mapping step

Tags: typescript, fp-ts

I'm wondering if there is a more concise and efficient way to achieve the following code:

```js
import { pipe } from 'fp-ts/function'
import * as A from 'fp-ts/Array'
import * as E from 'fp-ts/Option'

pipe(
  O.some(['foo', 'bar', 'baz']), // O.Option<string[]>
  O.map(A.map(mapFn)), // O.Option<Array<O.Option<string>>>
  O.chain(A.sequence(O.Applicative)), // O.Option<Array<string>>
)
```

Perhaps the root enclosing `Option` is detracting from the main point, but I'm basically trying to achieve the following transformation `T[] -> Option<T[]>` through mapping with `mapFn` which does `T -> Option<T>`.

I would be happy with this working example, although I can't help but notice that the `A.map` step completes entirely before the `A.sequence` step. If I could combine these two steps, then as soon as an element is mapped to `O.None` it would break (and not map the following elements unnecessarily).

Answer (score 0):

While writing this question, I discovered the `traverseArray` utility function which exists on `Option` and `Either`.

Now I'm able to perform the following and achieve the improved efficiency I mentioned at the end of the question. Whenever an element is mapped to a `None`, then traversal ends and passes a `None` to the next stage in the pipe.

```js
pipe(
  O.some(['foo', 'bar', 'baz']), // O.Option<string[]>,
  O.chain(O.traverseArray(mapFn)), // O.Option<string[]>,
)
```

Comment: If you answered your own question, please mark it by accepting it as the official answer.

Comment: Yes, `traverse` is `sequence` with mapping. Or, put another way, `sequence` is a specific usage of `traverse` with `identity` as the mapper